# Compiling gdb for armv6

Tags: gdb

I am trying to build gdb for armv6 architecture. I will be compiling this package on a Fedora Linux-Intel x86 box. I read the process of installing the gdb, like

1. Download the source pachage
2. run `configure -host`
3. `make`

But I got lost in the process because I was not able to make out what will be the host, target, needed for the `configure` script.

I need to basically be able to debug programs running on armv6 architecture board which runs linux kernel 2.6.21.5-cfs-v19. The gdb executable which I intend to obtain after compilation of the source also needs to be able to run on above mentioned configuration.

Now to get a working gdb executable for this configuration what steps should I follow?

Answer (score 2):

We (www.rockbox.org) use the arm target for a whole batch of our currently working DAPS. The target we specify is usually arm-elf, rather than arm-linux.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with `arm-linux` vs. `arm-elf`, eg.

- http://sources.redhat.com/ml/crossgcc/2005-11/msg00028.html

  > arm-elf is a standalone toolchain which does not require an underlying OS. So you can use
  >   it to generate programs using newlib
  >
  > arm-linux is a toolchain targetted to generate code for linux OS running on an ARM machine

We sometimes say `arm-elf` is for "bare metal".
Unfortunately there's another "bare metal" target `arm-eabi` and no one knows what the difference between these two exactly is.

BTW,

> The gdb executable which i intend to obtain after compilation of the source,also needs to be able to run on above mentioned configuration.

Really? Running GDB on an ARM board may be quite slow.
I recommend you either of

1. Remote debugging of the ARM board from an x86 PC
2. Saving a memory core on the ARM board, transferring it to an x86 PC and then inspecting it there

Cf.

- http://elinux.org/GDB
- [Cross-platform, multithreaded debugging (x86 to ARM) with gdb and gdbserver not recognizing threads](http://old.nabble.com/Cross-platform,-multithreaded-debugging-%28x86-to-ARM%29-with-gdb-and-gdbserver-not-recognizing-threads-td26820064.html)
- http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/remote-debugging

Comment: "2.  Saving a memory core on the ARM board, transferring it to an x86 PC and then inspecting it there" won't he/she need to also transfer all the libraries that the application uses included libc?  Otherwise the backtrace could be entirely random?

Comment: Yes, personally I like the cross-debootstrap tool on Debian which can create a complete file system hierarchy for an ARM device on my x86 development machine.  But I suppose similar tools are available for other Linux distros. By googling "arm chroot" I found several possible alternatives like http://wiki.meego.com/ARM/chroot http://blog.coralic.nl/2010/08/12/creating-chroot-for-arm-on-ubuntu-with-rootstock/

Answer (score 0):

target/host is usually the target tool chain you would be using (mostly arm-linux)